# How to set only the overflow flag ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, flags

I have been messing around with the Flags while learning ARM assembly on my Raspberry PI. I have devised of ways only to set the zero flag, only the negative, and only the carry flag. However I can't think of a way to set only the overflow flag. Is it possible? Any help would be appreciated!

The challenge is not to write to the cpsr (as I am not allowed to for various reasons, otherwise that would be the best solution, because it is the best solution)

Edit: only setting the overflow flag with all the others zero/clear. Using only arithmetic or shifting.
NZCV = 0001

Edit2: To clarify further, I would think multiple instructions would be needed to achieve this.

Comment: Do you mean with an `add` instruction or something that leaves all the other flags cleared?   `0x80000000 - 1` should set V without setting any other flags, wrapping from INT_MIN to INT_MAX.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Yes for the hex but’s would go far as to say any arithmetic or shifting.

Comment: @PeterCordes ARM does not invert the carry out like other architectures so you get a signed and unsigned overflow at the same time.  Carry out is not a borrow on ARM

Comment: Hmm which ARM?  I would assume that arm would not change that kind of thing with aarch64.

Comment: I am thinking not but you can try an experiment if you like.

Comment: Are you limited to a single instruction or can you use as many as you want?

Comment: are you allowed to simply write to the psr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see an obvious way with just one instruction, but you could do with combination. For example:

```
mov  r0, #0x80000000
mov  r1, #0x00000001
subs r2, r0, r1  ; C and V set
mov  r3, #0x10
asrs r3, #1      ; C cleared, V not changed
```

Comment: You could tighten that up if you wanted to, e.g. `mov r1, #0x10` / `subs r2, r0,  r1, lsr #4` to reuse one constant.  Or maybe use the barrel shifter so you don't need two separate inputs regs to start with either.  Like `mov r0, #0x80000002` should be encodeable with a rotated 8-bit constant, and `adds r0, r0, r0` produces `r0 = 4` with C and V set, ready for an `asrs`.

Answer (score 2):

```
abc cr
000 00 
001 01  x
010 01 
011 10 
100 01 
101 10 
110 10  x
111 11
```

Signed overflow is when carry out is not equal to carry in. If the first columns are msbits of operand a b and carry in to the msbit (other bits don't matter for signed nor unsigned overflow), the right columns are carry out and result.  If the result is 1 then you get the N bit. So it has to be with the msbits of the operands being 1 and the carry in being a 0

```
0xxx (carrys)
1xxx (operand a)
1xxx (operand b)

0x80 + 0x80 = 0x00 (zero flag)
0x81 + 0x81 = 0x02 (need some other ones)

  100000010
   10000001
+  10000001
============
   00000010
```

-127 + -127 = -254  the largest negative you can get is -128, 0x80, so this is a signed overflow.

But there is a carry out, isn't there?

So maybe a subtract will work  -127 - 127

```
  100000011
   10000001
+  10000000
============
   00000010
```

But being a subtract does it invert the carry out to a borrow leaving a 0 in the carry bit?  That is not how ARM works, other processors/cores will do this.

So in order to be able to do this you need a processor that defines the carry out as a borrow for a subtract (inverts the carry out at the end of the addition).

You edited your question while writing this, how would a shift operation modify a signed overflow?  Needs to be add or subtract (needs to use an adder).

Comment: Note that signed overflow is when carry out is not equal to carry in *for the sign bit* (the MSB), not for the computation as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

I'm relatively new to assembly and while experimenting and researching I have found the following way to set a single flag. Note that, I'm using ARM7TDMI-S based 32-bit RISC Microcontroller architecture. There are so-called **MRS** and **MSR** instructions. **MRS** is used to read the flags and **MSR** is used to write the flags.

---

Here is how I set each flag:

```
msr cpsr_cxsf, #0x80000000 ; N Flag
    
msr cpsr_cxsf, #0x40000000 ; Z flag
    
msr cpsr_cxsf, #0x20000000 ; C Flag
    
msr cpsr_cxsf, #0x10000000 ; V Flag
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to get this V=1 C=0 with a positive result (Z=0 N=0) from a single arithmetic instruction on ARM that writes all four flags, regardless of register inputs.  So @domen's answer using a shift to clear C and other flags while leaving V unmodified might be the best we can do other than `msr` to simply set CPSR directly.

Arithmetic in general is allowed in the question, but [`mul` leaves V unmodified](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0308/d/Thumb-Instructions/Alphabetical-list-of-Thumb-instructions/MUL), and `mls`/`mla`/[`smull`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0308/d/Thumb-Instructions/Alphabetical-list-of-Thumb-instructions/SMULL) and friends don't set flags.  Shifts like [`lsl`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0308/d/Thumb-Instructions/Alphabetical-list-of-Thumb-instructions/LSL--immediate-) also leave V unmodified, like bitwise instructions such as `and`.  Overflowing [`sdiv`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0308/d/Thumb-Instructions/Alphabetical-list-of-Thumb-instructions/SDIV) of `INT_MIN/-1` doesn't leave any trace: `sdiv` doesn't set flags at all.

---

Addition and subtraction set all four flags, but subtraction sets C as a not-borrow output if you look at it as actual binary subtraction.  (ARM subtraction of `x - y` sets the Carry flag as if from add-with-carry with `x + ~y` with carry-in = 1.)

- We need the result to be non-zero so Zero is clear
- We need the result to be non-negative so Negative is clear, thus we need the result to be positive.
- We need Carry to be clear, so we can't add `negative + negative => positive`; their sign bits would carry out into C.  And `positive+positive` overflowing to negative would set N.
  **So we can't use addition.**

Subtraction can signed-overflow with `positive-negative => negative`, which we don't want.
Or with `negative-positive => positive`.  But negative numbers are unsigned-higher than positive numbers so these subtractions don't produce a borrow.  Thus they *do* set C.  ([`bhi`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0308/d/The-Thumb-Instruction-Set/Conditional-execution/Assembly-language-syntax?lang=en) branches when C is set and Z is clear.)

**So neither overflow condition for subtraction can avoid setting C.**  (At least without considering `adc` / `sbc`, not sure if those help.)

Here's one way that's fairly compact and efficient: start with a `subs` that sets flags the way we want except for `N`, then a shift that overwrites all the flags other than `V`.

```
.syntax unified

  movs  r0, #0x80                  // fits in a Thumb 16-bit mov reg, imm8 (zero-extended)
  subs  r0, r0, r0, lsl #24        // NZCV=1001 from 0x80 - INT_MIN (0x80000000) overflowing to negative result 0x80000080
  lsrs  r0, #1                     // R0 = 0x40000040,  NZCV=0001  (checked with QEMU + LLDB)
```

In Thumb-2 machine code, 2 of the instructions are 16-bit.  I haven't thought of a way to make all 3 instructions have 16-bit Thumb encodings, with this or any other strategy.

```
       0: 2080          movs    r0, #0x80
       2: ebb0 6000     subs.w  r0, r0, r0, lsl #24
       6: 0840          lsrs    r0, r0, #0x1
```

#### With borrow/carry inputs to `sbc`/`adc`?  No, doesn't help

`0 - (1<<31) - 1` is `0x7fffffff`, which is like `0 - INT_MIN - 1`.  Doing that as all one operation is like `0 - (INT_MIN + 1)`, subtracting a negative from 0 and getting a positive without overflow.  Doing that with ARM instructions like [`rscs r0, #0`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/arm-and-thumb-instructions/rsc) clears both C and V flags.

`0 - 0x7fffffff - 1` produces `0x80000000` = INT_MIN, so it's not even signed overflow.  Subtracting from a positive won't either, but subtracting from a negative number would.  But negative numbers are unsigned-higher than positive numbers, so the subtraction wouldn't have a borrow, so `-3 - 0x7fffffff - 1` makes C=0.  And we didn't need `sbc` if we start with negative numbers lower than `-1`, so that's not helping.

`0 + 0x80000000 + 1` with `adc` doesn't help, that's `INT_MIN + 1` which doesn't have signed overflow and is negative.  Any signed overflow involving addition either has carry or a negative result, even with `adc`.

So none of `adc`, `sbc`, or ARM-mode-only `rsc` help here.